# How to unit test whether a file was moved from a local directory to an ActiveMQ queue

Tags: spring-boot, junit, apache-camel

I am new to apache camel and am currently working on unit testing of a folder watcher system. I have a simple route builder that looks at one directory and if the application is run that file is deleted from that directory and then moved to an activeMQ queue.

My question is how do I go about testing this? If I was to run the unit tests I want to be able to see that the folder that moves the file is actually doing as such and that the activeMQ is receiving that file.

I'm sorry if this is very vague, I can offer clarification where I can, this is more of a high-level question just to help me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

So, when I understand your question correct, you have something like this

```
from("file:path/to/importdir?delete=true")
    .to("activemq:queue:myFileQueue")
```

If this (or similar) is your route, in my opinion, you **don't need to write unit tests at all**.

Why? Because **all you would test is the Camel components**, but they are very well tested in the Camel project.

Start to **write route tests if you have any "route logic"**.

For example to make sure a [content based routing](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/content-based-router-eip.html) is working correct and different test messages are taking the correct paths in the route.